# how to export auto generated machine key

Tags: asp.net, iis, oauth, owin, machinekey

I have been using owin oauth bearer tokens for web.api authentication. I had only a single server. I never needed to custom generate a machine key. Right now, I need to move to a web farm behind a load balancer. I dont want my current users' bearer tokens to become invalid when I move to the farm. How do I export an auto generated machine key, and import to to another server?

Comment: It would be good if you accepted some of your answers if they're helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file deployed on each server must have the same machine key. Some reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations).

Basically you have to copy this section to the other servers' config file:

```
<machineKey validationKey="A970D0E3C36AA17C43C5DB225C778B3392BAED4D7089C6AAF76E3D4243E64FD797BD17611868E85D2E4E1C8B6F1FB684B0C8DBA0C39E20284B7FCA73E0927B20" decryptionKey="88274072DD5AC1FB6CED8281B34CDC6E79DD7223243A527D46C09CF6CA58DB68" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

It's always best to use a [script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218#AppendixA) to generate your own machine keys.